# SFDX enable Asset Sharing Scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

How can we enable Asset Sharing as we create a scratch org?

The only way I know to enable it is by switching to classic and navigating to it on the Setup menu. I would like to script this or define it in the project-scratch-def.json so I can spin up a scratch org as a pre-commit hook.

Answer (score 1):

you can add it in the `project-scratch-def.json`. Just add the following there.

```
"sharingSettings": {
    "enableAssetSharing": true
}
```